# Running unit tests is giving me different code coverage every time I run test using React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

as the title mentions I am trying to run test cases for a component in react using react testing library. After running tests when I check code coverage it changes between 66%, 84% and 100% randomly, even if no changes in the code or test file is made.

All the test cases for that component are passing just fine. what could be the issue? I cant seem to figure things out.

For building UI in components, I'm using Material UI. (just putting it out there if it may help.)

**Edit**
here is my my component. (I have simplified it a bit since i cannot share the whole thing)

**MyComponent.js**

```
const MyComponent = ()=>{

    return<>
    {/* Other components */}
    <Typography
                  
                  style={{ display: 'flex' }}
                  data-testid='delete-pop-up-opener'
                  {/* this handle click enables the popover*/}
                  onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, item?.id)}> 
                  <img
                    src={ElipsesIcon}
                    alt='Elipses Icon'
                    data-testid='elipses-icon' />
                </Typography>
                <Popover
                  data-testId='popover-delete'
                  open={some_flag_to_on_popover}
                  onClose={handleClose}
                  onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                  >
                  <Box
                    data-testid='delete-pop-up-button'
                    onClick={() => delteHandler(item)}>
                    <Typography>
                      <IconButton>
                        <DeleteOutlineIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography>Delete Item</Typography>
                  </Box>
                </Popover>
    {/* Other components */}
    
    </>
  }
```

test snippet.
**test.js**

```
test('to see if delete button is working and deleting item', async () => {  
    const component = render(
      <MyComponent/>
    );
    expect(screen.queryAllByTestId('delete-pop-up-opener')).toHaveLength(1);
    const opener = screen.queryAllByTestId('delete-pop-up-opener')[0];
    await waitFor(async () =>
      UserEvent.click(opener), { timeout: 10000 }
    );
    expect(screen.queryAllByTestId('delete-pop-up-button')).toHaveLength(1);
    await waitFor(async () =>
      UserEvent.click(screen.queryAllByTestId('delete-pop-up-button')[0]), { timeout: 10000 });
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

**note:** I've also noticed that testing single test script individually works just fine. All the test cases pass, and code coverage is proper as well. But running all tests suites makes code coverage inconsistent.

Comment: The code snippet of your component and the snippet of your test will help more to understand and resolve the issue

Comment: @OWS I've added the code snippet. I've simplified it a bit since I cannot share the whole thing, so let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I guess try creating the issue in codesandbox. But lets see. Why are you doing `queryAllByTestId('delete-pop-up-button')[0]`, there should be only one, use screen.debug() to see what is rendered and why there is timeout. You mentioned coverage, but you have only one test. You are doing snapshot testing make sure you are getting it same every time or not

Comment: @ows okay so i've been trying out different things, and i found that running command  `npx jest --all --coverage` gives expected output. where as `npm run start` has inconsistent results. so i guess i have to look for jest config issues